# Switch case card class

Tags: java, switch-statement

Main Class:

```
public class Card
{
private String cardShort;
private String cardClas;
private String cardType;
public Card(String cardClas, String cardType)
{
    this.cardType = cardType;
    this.cardClas = cardClas;
}
public void cardSelector()
{
    switch(cardClas.toUpperCase())
    {
            case "J" : cardClas = "Jack";
                  break;
            case "K" : cardClas = "King";
                  break;
            case "Q" : cardClas = "Queen";
                  break;
            case "A" : cardClas = "Ace";
                  break; 
            case "2" : cardClas = "Two";
                  break;
            case "3" : cardClas = "Three";
                  break;
            case "4" : cardClas = "Four";
                  break;
            case "5" : cardClas = "Five";
                  break;
            case "6" : cardClas = "Six";
                  break; 
            case "7" : cardClas = "Seven";
                  break; 
            case "8" : cardClas = "Eight";
                  break;
            case "9" : cardClas = "Nine";
                  break; 
            case "10" : cardClas = "Ten";
                  break;                       
    }
    switch(cardType.toUpperCase())
    {
        case "S" : cardClas = "Spades";
                  break; 
        case "C" : cardClas = "Clubs";
                  break;
        case "H" : cardClas = "Hearts";
                  break; 
        case "D" : cardClas = "Diamonds";
                  break;                
    }
}
public String getClasses()
{
    return cardType;
}
public String getType()
{
    return cardClas;
}
public String toString()
{
    String theory = getClasses() + " of " + getType();
    return theory;
}
```

}

Tester:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CardTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter card: ");
    String shortHand = sc.next();

    if(shortHand.length() == 2)
    {
        Card c = new Card(shortHand.substring(0,1),shortHand.substring(1,2) );
        c.cardSelector();
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    } else if(shortHand.length() == 3)
    {
        Card c = new Card(shortHand.substring(0,2), shortHand.substring(2,3));
        c.cardSelector();
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Console:
"Enter card: 
AS
S of Spades
"
Supposed to output "Ace of Spades". Tried a bunch of different fixes, not sure what is causing the problem right now.

First time using switch case, could use some help... Thanks!

Comment: Well, have you stepped through your code in the debugger?

Comment: This is exactly the scenario where you want to use type-safe enums. They would have prevented this error.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your switch statements are setting `cardClas`.  You need one of them to set `cardType` instead.

Also, your two getters are very confusing.  You seem to have swapped the names over somehow; so you have `getClasses` returning `cardType` and `getType` returning `cardClas`.  You might want to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

First I hope you are using Java 7.  If not (or if you want to just simplify it) you can use char instead of String in your switch statements.  Also at the same time you are setting cardClas in both switch statements.  Also your method getClasses returns cardType and your getCardType returns cardClas